# Existence of an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

I would like the prove the following result. Thanks for any help in advance.

Let $v_1$, $v_2$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R^{n}}$. If |$v_1$| = |$v_2$|, then there exists an orthogonal matrix $\Gamma$ such that $\Gamma$$v_1$= $v_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_1=v_1/|v_1|$, $y_1=v_2/|v_2|$. Then we can extend $x_1$ to an orthonormal basis $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, and $y_1$ to an orthonormal basis $y_n$. Define $\Gamma$ as the linear operator with $\Gamma(x_j)=y_j$. That is 
$$
\Gamma(\sum_{k=1}^nt_kx_k)=\sum_{k=1}^nt_ky_k.
$$
Since both $\{x_j\}$ and $\{y_j\}$ are basis, $\Gamma$ is well-defined. We have 
$$
(\Gamma x)\cdot(\Gamma x)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^nt_ky_k\right)
\cdot\left(\sum_{k=1}^nt_ky_k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^nt_k^2=x\cdot x,
$$
so $\Gamma$ is orthogonal. And
$$
\Gamma(v_1)=\Gamma(|v_1|\,x_1)=|v_1|\,y_1=|v_2|\,y_1=v_2.
$$

Answer (score 2):

For $v_1$ and $v_2$, consider the linear function that reflects $v_2$ onto $v_1$ with respect to the vector between them which is $w=\frac{v_1+v_2}2$:

$$
\Gamma v=2\frac{v.w}{w.w}w-v.
$$ 
Firstly see that:
$$
\Gamma v_1=2\frac{v_1.w}{w.w}w-v_1=2\frac{v_1.(v_1+v_2)}{(v_1+v_2)(v_1+v_2)}(v_1+v_2)-v_1\\
=2\frac{v_1.(v_1+v_2)}{(v_1+v_2)(v_1+v_2)}v_2+\frac{(v_2-v_1).(v_1+v_2)}{(v_1+v_2)(v_1+v_2)}v_1=2\frac{|v_1|^2+v_1.v_2}{2|v_1|^2+2v_1.v_2}v_2=v_2.
$$
To check orthogonality, see that:
$$
\Gamma u.\Gamma v=(2\frac{u.w}{w.w}w-u).(2\frac{v.w}{w.w}w-v)\\
=u.v-2\frac{u.w}{w.w}w.v-2\frac{v.w}{w.w}w.u+4\frac{u.w}{w.w}\frac{u.w}{w.w}w.w=u.v.
$$

Comment: I'm confused. What is $\Gamma$?

Comment: $\Gamma$ is the linear transformation, like your question.